# Python: How to pass a variable from a method within a method?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I'm working a script that checks to see if a username is being used on a large list of forums that uses Xenforo. The list is actually 2 separate lists, one for each version of Xenforo( since each versions require slightly different code).

I'm trying use a class with 3 methods, not counting **init**. Forgive me as this is my first time using classes.

```
class Xenforo:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def iterurl(self, inputfile):
        with open(inputfile, "r") as f:
            for item in f:
                item2 = item.strip()
                payload = {'login':self.name}

                response = requests.post(item2, data=payload)
                soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
        return soup

    def check1(self):
        self.iterurl("version1.txt")

        name_result = soup.find("div", class_="blockMessage blockMessage--error blockMessage--iconic").text.strip()

        if name_result == "Incorrect password. Please try again.":
            print("user found")
        elif name_result == "The requested user '"+self.name+"' could not be found.":
            print("user not found")
        else:
            print("possible error")

        print(name_result)

    def check2(self):


        payload = {'login': self.name}

        response = requests.post(self.url, data=payload)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
        try:
            name_result = soup.find("div", class_="errorPanel").find("li").text.strip()
            if name_result == "User names must be unique. The specified user name is already in use.":
                print("user found")
            else:
                print("user not found")
        except AttributeError:
            print("user not found")
```

Essentially I want to use iterurl() in both check1() and check2(), since the first half of the code is identical except for the name of text file( keep in mind I haven't reworked the code for check2() yet).

I'm not sure I'm calling iterurl() within check1() properly. Most importantly how can a pass soup  from iterurl() with check1() to the rest of the code within check1?

This code doesn't recognize soup from iterurl as existing:

```
 name_result = soup.find("div", class_="blockMessage blockMessage--error blockMessage--iconic").text.strip()
```

How can I pass soup the check1 pythonically?

Comment: I think you mean `b.iterurl("version1.txt")`. Not sure what you're calling it as though it's static. Also, are you sure you want to create a new instance (`b`) and not just use `self`?

Comment: ill edit it to reflect that, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of the call to iterutil is soup so

```
def check1(self):
    soup = self.iterutil(“version1.txt”)
    soup.foo()
    ....
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks i'll remember that from now on.